# AngularJS: Kendo slider show label for every tick

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI Core Slider. The default label for ticks appear every 5.

The sliders I created have a dynamic max so at times may only be 3 or 4. In this case, the user only sees 0 (as a min) and a few ticks.

```
<input kendo-slider="" k-min="0" k-max="{{scores.scoreTotal}}" k-tooltip="{ enabled: false }"  ng-model="modalOptions.evaluatorScore[$index]" />
```

How can I have a label appear for every tick?

Comment: Haven't used Kendo but just figured I'd put this out there, I made a simple slider control that is mobile friendly and just depends on SVG directly.  If you can't find a solution and are interested in contributing adding the ticks code, so far it's pretty simple http://shusain.github.io/itSlides/dist/ for source https://github.com/shusain/itSlides/blob/master/app/component/component.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look to the smallStep and largeStep configuration options.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/slider#configuration-largeStep

Slightly modified...

```
<input kendo-slider="" k-min="0" k-small-step="1" k-large-step="1" k-max="{{scoreTotal}}" k-tooltip="{ enabled: false }" />
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/azAMO